# Springboot Unit Tesiting with Jwt spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, jwt

I am a Newbie to Unit Testing/ Integration Testing
I am getting some errors while testing the rest api which is secured with Jwt Token authentication by spring security.

**userControllerTest**

```
@ExtendWith({ RestDocumentationExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "target/generated-snippets")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationContext.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@WithMockUser
class UserControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private IUserService<User> userService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @Spy
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired 
    private JwtUtility jwtUtil;


    @Spy
    private JwtRequestFilter filer;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Spy
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private final static String ACCEPT_TYPE = "application/user-details";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders

                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation).snippets()
                        .withDefaults(HttpDocumentation.httpRequest(), HttpDocumentation.httpResponse()))// .apply(springSecurity())
                .addFilters(new JwtRequestFilter()).build();
    }

    private User getUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1L);
        user.setFirstName("Saurabh");
        user.setLastName("Kohade");
        user.setEmail("user@cc.com");
        user.setReseller(null);
        user.setRoleName("ADMIN");
        return user;
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Will create User")
//  @WithAnonymousUser
    void testCreate() throws Exception {

        User entity = getUser();

        when(userService.saveUser(entity, 1L)).thenReturn(entity);

        UserDto dtoresponse = userController.create(entity, ACCEPT_TYPE);

        assertNotNull(dtoresponse);

        String token = "Bearer JhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiuY29tIiwicmVzZWxsZXJJbmZvIjoie1wiZG9tYWluTmFtZTgQ.W0Xnl1j7PAAxqV97uE6s6iGU1IfCZHmiVLYN5iZwsbI";

        String URI = "/user";

        String inputToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
                .perform(post(URI).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt())
                        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(inputToJson).accept(ACCEPT_TYPE))//.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());

    }
```

**junit Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$JwtRequestPostProcessor.<init>(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors$JwtRequestPostProcessor.<init>(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java:262)
    at cloudcodes.customermanagement.controller.UserControllerTest.testCreate(UserControllerTest.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 71 more
```

I think i am missing some configuration for authentication to fake token can anyone help me with this?.....

Comment: Include your POM, and don't use `application/user-details`; that's not a valid MIME type, and types must be registered. You can get a custom `application/vnd.` namespace, but just use `application/json` so everything will understand how to interpret it.

Comment: ok thanks for tanswering @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic but the issue i am facing is to authenticate token in my test case which i need to pass in my authorization as bearer token for every request of my application i need to verify this token so i need to implement that structure in my test cases